# Javascript remove class="d-none" function not defined HTMLSpanElement.onclick (Uncaught ReferenceError)

Tags: javascript, python, html, jquery, django

I'm trying to link a Javascript remove function (i.e. the ability to hide/unhide a dropdown menu) from a button on my website's navigation bar. When I run my server clicking the button doesn't do anything, and my console is giving me an Uncaught ReferenceError:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: showNotifications is not defined
> at HTMLSpanElement.onclick ((index):61:135)

`social.js`:

```
function showNotifications() {
    const container = document.getElementById('notification-container');

    if (container.classList.contains('d-none')) {
        container.classList.remove('d-none');
    } else {
        container.classList.add('d-none');
    }
}
```

The HTML document the function is linked to:
`show_notifications.html`:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <span class="badge notification-badge" style="background-color: #d7a5eb;" onclick="showNotifications()">{{ notifications.count }}</span>
    <div class="dropdown-content d-none" id="notification-container">
        {% for notification in notifications %}
            {% if notification.post %}
                {% if notification.notification_type == 1 %}
                <div class="dropdown-item-parent">
                    <a href="#">@{{ notification.from_user }} liked your post</a>
                    <span class="dropdown-item-close">&times;</span>
                </div>
                {% elif notification.notification_type == 2 %}
                <div class="dropdown-item-parent">
                    <a href="#">@{{ notification.from_user }} commented on your post</a>
                    <span class="dropdown-item-close">&times;</span>
                </div>
                {% endif %}
            {% elif notification.comment %}
                {% if notification.notification_type == 1 %}
                <div class="dropdown-item-parent">
                    <a href="#">@{{ notification.from_user }} liked on your comment</a>
                    <span class="dropdown-item-close">&times;</span>
                </div>
                {% elif notification.notification_type == 2 %}
                <div class="dropdown-item-parent">
                    <a href="#">@{{ notification.from_user }} replied to your comment</a>
                    <span class="dropdown-item-close">&times;</span>
                </div>
                {% endif %}
            {% else %}
            <div class="dropdown-item-parent">
                <a href="#">@{{ notification.from_user }} has started following you</a>
                <span class="dropdown-item-close">&times;</span>
            </div>
            {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
```

I've tried to remain concise, but please let me know if you need any further code to identify the issue :)

Comment: Are you sure you have loaded the `social.js` which includes `function showNotifications()` before clicking on the ` span`  badge ?

Comment: Excuse the silly question, but how exactly would I go about doing that?

Comment: You need something like `<script src="/path-to-your-social.js-file/social.js"></script>` in your HTML source to load the `social.js` and the `function` definition.

Comment: Hmm.. just tried adding that in and my localhost's console is still giving me the same ReferenceError